# To use a foreign key in MySQL or not to?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have been coding with MySQL DBs for a couple years now and I have never used a  foreign key. Now, I understand that a foreign key is like an ID on one table that corresponds with a primary key of another table.  I have a user table on my site and probably around 10 other tables that all correspond with the primary key of my user table - however they are not set as  foreign keys.

What am I missing out on by not having these 10 other tables have a  foreign key?  I mean, as far as I can tell they basically *are* a  foreign key except they do not have that value saved/assigned to them in the DB.

Is there some other benefit here that I am just not aware of?

I realize too that a primary key cannot be null, but a  foreign key can be. This will never be an issue in my case as my user table is created, and and when a new user is added to my user table I add their appropriate entry to the 10 other tables.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of "you can do that yourself in code" in answers here, and it's seriously misguided. I cannot count how many databases I have seen that have become a mess of invalid data over the course of months and years. Without exception, every one of them would have been perfectly clean had referential integrity been properly enforced in the schema. Foreign keys are not optional -- they are a key component of good database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` serves two purposes:

- It ensures that you relationships are always consistent at the cost of some checking overhead
- It (disputably) simplifies cascaded updates and deletes.

In most cases, this functionality can be more efficiently implemented using other tools.

Comment: Disagree here. You then assume that there will be always extra layer over the DB serving the purposes which the DB already has. I see that this becomes quite modern approach but still consider it quite bad.

Comment: @Jan: layer normally used for that is called stored procedures, and it's not "over" the `DB`. The main disadvantage of the foreign keys is their row-by-row implementation which is a performance killer if you need to do mass updates on a more or less regular basis.

Comment: So you will create for each table something like before insert trigger to enforce the constraint? Is it really more efficient? Just asking, not saying it is not. Really curious. Because you can make something like api of stored procedures which should be used for inserting/updating data, but is it 100% safe? What if someone calls the insert directly?

Comment: @Jan: I create a stored procedure which handles inserts, updates and deletes from the table (actually, I have a script which creates a default procedure from the tables' definitions). The procedures accept a set as an input (all major engines except MySQL support it) which is definitely more efficient than a series of individual inserts. It's impossible to call `INSERT` directly because it's not granted on tables, only `EXECUTE` on procs. Performance benefits are obvious only for mass updates, however, I've developed the scripts long since and use this approach even for pure `OLTP` apps.

Comment: If this is the case I agree with you. +1 and taking back my first DIsagree comment. Thanks for making this clear, it wasn't so obvious from your answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding foreign keys is always a good idea - at least I've never seen a compelling reason not to use them.

- enforces referential integrity (can't delete a parent if a child exists, can't insert orphans, or a child with an invalid parent id)
- works as an index
- With foreign keys, no matter how the data is accessed, whether through an app, an automated process, or someone without caffeine at the terminal the rules are uniformly enforced.

Comment: scale hard when use foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

With foreign keys you

- can make sure that only valid user_id's are put to those fields
- use cascades on delete easier don't
- don't have to manually define indexes on those fields (innodb)

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing out on is enforced referential integrity (i.e. if your other table has `user_id` 27, there MUST be an ID 27 in the user table) and the ability to have automatic cascade updates and deletes (i.e. if you delete user 27, the corresponding rows in the other table are also automatically deleted, etc).

In my opinion, it's not worth it.  I'm perfectly capable of having my code address referential integrity, and dealing with foreign keys is an *enormous* maintenance annoyance.

Comment: Currently when a user deletes an account I have my code delete from the other 10+ tables, you are saying this could all be automated?  I am more curious about you mention update, what will that do

Comment: @chaos: I'm sure your code is always flawless in its enforcement of referential integrity, but what about *other* people's code that accesses the same database?  Or ad hoc queries run in a query tool?  The point of database-enforced RI is that it's consistent even if the client is not.

Answer (score 0):

In some databases (not sure about MySQL), a `FOREIGN KEY` automatically indexes, which nicely speeds up your joins and queries on foreign keys.  Plus, there's the already-mentioned benifits of cascading deletes, referential integrity, etc.

Comment: Defining a foreign key in MySQL is basically an alias for setting up 1) an index 2) a constraint (the actual fkey), so yeah, you get an index out of it.